# Find the set of convergence series as $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $A=\{x>0\mid \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt[n]{x}-1) \text{ is convergence series}\}$.

How we can obtain $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\sqrt[n]{x}=\exp\left(\frac1n\ln x\right)\sim1+ \frac1n\ln x+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
hence we see by asymptotic comparison that the series is convergent if and only if $x=1$ which means that the general term of the series is $0$.

Comment: why the series is convergent iff $x=1$ ?

Comment: If $x\ne1$ then $\sqrt[n]{x}-1\sim\frac{\ln x}n$ and we know that the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: oh yes, very thanks

Comment: You're welcome.